# BDD: How should I test authentication when I use Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, tdd, bdd

You write the tests, make them fail and then write *your code* to make them pass. Simple... until you decide to use a *gem* instead of your code. Devise, for example.

I really don't know what integration (aka request or feature) specs I should write.

If I don't write anything I have to open the browser to check if the integration of the gem with the application is ok, and this is bad (cfr. Ryan Bates). Also, I may mistakenly break a functionality.

On the other side is incorrect and useless to test other's code.

What is the right balance? How can I do BDD (with RSpec) when adding Devise?

**A concrete example of what you would write as a test for authorization when using Devise would be greatly appreciated.**

How would you answer the same questions if you had custom Devise views inside your application?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely achieve this using Capybara and Rspec.

Install capybara following instructions here https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec - tip, make sure you name the directory where you spec is to `features`

Then simply use capybara to test drive your applications

So to test your sign up this example should work, obviously you'll need to adjust the parameters and routes based on your application.

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'Signing up' do
  scenario 'creates a new user' do
    visit '/users/sign_up'
    password = 'samplepassword'
    fill_in 'First name', with: 'Testy'
    fill_in 'Last name', with: 'McTester'
    fill_in 'Email', with: 'testy@example.com'
    fill_in 'Password', with: password
    fill_in 'Password confirmation', with: password
    click_link 'Sign up'
    expect(page).to have_content 'You have signed up successfully'
  end
end
```

Devise also has test helpers which you can use when testing other areas of your app https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers

These can be particularly useful for ensuring that any restrictions you place on various pages are correct.  You can test this behaviour by testing what happens if the user is signed in or has the wrong role etc.

Comment: +1 But besides a practical guide on how to test authentication in general (which I already know), I would like to have a theorical discussion on what should be tested and what should not be tested when using code (like a gem) which have already been tested.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with the following reflections:

- a semantic reason is that high level testing (e.g. RSpec with Capybara) means you are describing the features of your site, and authentication is still a feature, even if you use a gem
- a practical reason is that if I don't add tests I will certainly have to test authentication through the browser
- suppose you decide to remove the gem and rewrite authentication from scratch; this is refactoring, and because tests should allow refactoring without the need to change them, there is another reason to add high level testing from the beginning (even if you will use a gem)
- it is not necessary bad that you test a code which has already been tested, if you do it at another level of abstraction: for example functional testing and integration testing is always partially overlapping on unit testing
- you are not double testing the same things, because you are testing integration of the gem with your website, and this cannot have been already tested inside the gem

IMHO In conclusion there are more reasons to test, than not to test, an authentication system based on third-party gems.